# Travel plan has changed drastically after receiving Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, business-travel, schedule-change

I applied for a Schengen visa for Poland for business travel. I received a multi-entry visa with a validity of 1 year. After receiving my visa, I was requested by my client to cancel my trip to Poland, and was asked to travel to the Czech republic.

Therefore, I will now need to travel to Czechia WITHOUT even visiting Poland. Can I travel with my existing Poland visa? Or should I apply for a new visa with Czechia?
I still don't have a clear suggestion if I should apply for a new visa or if I should use my existing visa?

Comment: No, this doesn't answer my question. 
I would like to know if there are any consequences in traveling to a different country without having visited the visa-issuing country (Poland)? 
This is not explained in the above thread.

Comment: @Giridhar The accepted answer to the linked question states: 'if you don't use the visa for its intended purpose, border guards could in principle rule that the conditions for issuing it are no longer met and revoke it'. How does that not answer your question?

Comment: Was Poland to be your main destination?

Comment: It was, while applying for the visa. But in my actual trip, I will not even be visiting Poland.

Comment: I still don't have a clear suggestion ifI should apply for a new visa or if I should use my existing visa?

Comment: Informing the polish consulate of the changed situation (including the letter from your client) would be the best thing to do in such a murky situation. They could, in theory, add the information into the VIS system stating they have no objection. Otherwise they may tell you to apply again for the Czech republic, making a revoking request for the previous visa while doing so.

Comment: Hi Girdhar I have  had this experience an year ago now be prepared when you go to Prague the border guards will ask you to prove your entry reasons they hardly care about what’s your main destination though you have to give or show then valid reasons and maybe sufficient evidence like travel plans in my opinion it should be fine after all Schengen means common entry system so you should technically be allowed on valid grounds

Comment: @SaranshSharma The problem is that the OP's having chosen Poland as their "main destination" and obtained a visa from Poland _is no longer true_. Thus, the "valid grounds" of which you speak do not exist, as the OP's visa doesn't authorize the trip they're now planning to take.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica the valid grounds are actually decided by the border guards since the having visa does not necessarily means you could get an entry to the member states. Hence that why I say provide your justification to the country other than main